What is the difference between "the worst" and "the most extreme"?
Consider the following hypothetical: Alice and Bob are talking about tormenting childhoods. It's now Alice's turn to talk about her childhood. If Alice says "Being made a clotheshorse by my parents is the worst suffering I ever experienced" that invites the response from Bob "...then you must have not suffered much." But if Alice says "Being made a clotheshorse by my parents is the most extreme suffering I ever experienced", that is much less likely to provoke the same response from Bob.
Why is that?

How do you know "most extreme" is less likely to prompt that response? Note also that "most extreme" can have other meanings than "worst".

@Peter Part of learning the English language is learning the model of the language. In the model currently holding, "the worst" invites a different response than "the most extreme".

The only reason I would not have the same response is because I understand that "most extreme" could have other meanings. In other words I would need to think more before responding, and "what do you mean?" might be a more natural response.

What is this 'model currently holding' of which you speak?

What do you mean by 'being made a clotheshorse'? Why is that 'extreme suffering'?

@KateBunting I take it as "having a stage mom who put me in beauty pageants, or made me an Instagram influencer," or the like. And as Bob points out, while it might certainly be traumatizing, it's a bit of a "first word problem."

I’m voting to close this question because it rests on a misconception. Changing "worst" to "most extreme" in this case does little to change the meaning or its reception.

I think your statement about the difference responses to the phrases is simply wrong. "Being made a clotheshorse by my parents is the worst suffering I ever experienced" and "Being made a clotheshorse by my parents is the most extreme suffering I ever experienced" would elicit the same response.
In this context "worst" and "most extreme" are synonymous, but that is only because "suffering" is seen as intrinsically bad (putting masochists to one side for the moment). If you replaced "suffering" with "pleasure" the two sentences would have opposite meanings to each other.

I think it is incorrect to say "the worst suffering" would likely generate a negative response but "the most extreme suffering" would not. Both phrases mean pretty much the same thing. And "being made a clothes horse" doesn't seem like particularly bad suffering, so if someone said that was either the worst or the most extreme suffering ever, I'd think, Hey, if that's the worst (or most extreme) you've ever had to put up with, your life was pretty good. (Just today I was complaining because a certain app on my phone takes too many button presses to work. And then I said, "Well, not like that's extreme suffering. There are people in the world who are starving to death; I shouldn't complain about having to press three extra buttons.)
"Most extreme" is not generally the same as "worst". It could mean "best", like, "This is the most extremely good chocolate I have ever eaten." It could be subjective. Like, "Senator Jones is an extreme liberal" might sound like a good thing to other extreme liberals, a bad thing to conservatives, and maybe good or maybe troubling to moderate liberals. Etc.

Sometimes "worst" is the wrong word because it's subjective.  Climate scientists talk about "extreme temperatures" not "worst temperatures" because they want an objective measure.  A vacationer might say "We had the worst weather" to mean it was bad for vacationing but a week of rain might be exactly what the farmer wants. A constant drizzle is hardly "extreme weather".
So you have to ask yourself, for any given context, whether you're trying to express a subjective feeling about something, or trying to express something objective about it.
